# Measured temperature (thermometre set to emissivity of 1) of smooth surface too high or to low?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, thermal-radiation

We want to measure the temperature of a smooth flat surface with a thermometre based on absorption of thermal rays.

The emissivity setting of the thermometre is set to 1 (same as a black surface), which is wrong.

Now the question is, will the thermometre measure to high or too low temperature?
The answer is supposed to be that it measures to low, but I don't understand how to think of/analyze this type of situation. How do incoming rays affect temperature?

Since the surface is not black, it means it doesn't absorb all incoming radiation.

And since its smooth it means it doesn't reflect diffusely (in all directions equally), and smooth I guess also means that a incoming ray will reflect outwards in the same direction as the incoming.

Comment: A true thermometer in equilibrium will always show the correct answer. An IR radiometer is simply not a true thermometer but a proxy. If the emitting surface is grey, rather than black, the proxy algorithm will underestimate the temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radiation of a body is given by the Stefan-Boltzmann equation:

$$E= \epsilon \sigma T^4$$

Which means that if you can measure the radiated power $E$, the temperature is

$$T=\sqrt[4]{\frac{E}{\epsilon \sigma}}$$

If the emissivity is lower than you think, it follows that you see less emission that you would expect for a given temperature and you would underestimate the temperature.

Comment: aaah yeah thx, see the relation now, if the emissivity goes lower than one the temperature increases, and if the emissivity goes up to 1 which is the max, we get a lower temperature.
So in other words a black surface would be colder than a grey one because the black surface emits/gets rid of heat/energy most efficiently (more is not possible).

Comment: Not quite. The temperature is what it is - but when you measure the emitted power and assume a certain emissivity, you calculate the temperature that you believe would give rise to that. If the emissivity is less than you assume, then you _deduce_ (wrongly) that the temperature is lower than it is because the object radiates less (in the way that a colder object with higher emissivity would radiate).

Comment: yup I fully agree, temperature is what it is measured to be, that's  a more precise way of putting it as you explain